# Radiation Transport Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I am trying to solve the radiation transport equation $$-\frac{1}{\kappa_\lambda \rho} \frac{d I_\lambda}{ds} = I_\lambda - S_\lambda$$ for a light beam of intensity $I_\lambda$ which travels through a cloud of constant density $\rho$ and a constant opacity $\kappa_\lambda$. The source function $S_\lambda$ is constant. I tried solving it by separating the variables and I get $$\int \mathrm{d}I_\lambda \frac{1}{I_\lambda - S_\lambda} = - \int \mathrm{d}s \kappa_\lambda \rho \\
\Leftrightarrow I_\lambda = I_{\lambda,0}e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s} + S_\lambda$$

But according to my worksheet the solution has the form $$I_\lambda = I_{\lambda,0} e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s} + S_\lambda \left( 1 - e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s}\right)$$

I inserted my solution and the worksheet's solution into the differential equation and both solve the differential equation.

I don't understand how they got the $S_\lambda e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s}$ into their solution. Did they make assumptions I didn't make? I would really like some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving differential equations like this, you must either put a constant of integration or state the limits of the integrals. If you do so you get

$$\int_{I_{\lambda,0}}^{I_{\lambda}}\frac{{\rm d}I_{\lambda}}{I_{\lambda}+S_{\lambda}}=-\int_{0}^{s}{\rm d}s\kappa_{\lambda}\rho$$

$$\ln\left(\frac{I_{\lambda}-S_{\lambda}}{I_{\lambda,0}-S_{\lambda}}\right)=-\kappa_{\lambda}\rho s$$

which I am sure you can take from here. In other words your solution doesn't satisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: I used a constant of integration. I did the following $\int \mathrm{d}I_\lambda \frac{1}{I_\lambda - S_\lambda} = - \int \mathrm{ds} \kappa_\lambda \rho \Leftrightarrow \ln(I_\lambda - S_\lambda) = - \kappa_\lambda \rho s + C \Leftrightarrow I_\lambda = e^{C} e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s} + S_\lambda = I_{\lambda,0} e^{-\kappa_\lambda \rho s} + S_\lambda$ Where is my mistake in this approach? I assume I don't satisfy the boundary conditions but there were no boundary conditions given.

Comment: @Limechime The boundary condition is $I_{\lambda}\left(s=0\right)=I_{\lambda,0}$ which sets $e^{C}=I_{\lambda,0}-S_{\lambda}$.